# Loop and modify xml nodes SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to loop through xml nodes in SQL Server, and create a copy of each node containing ','.

For example, for the following xml :

```
 declare @answerXML xml = '<answers><answer part="1">answer,test0</answer><answer part="1">answer,test1</answer></answers>'
```

I want to be modified to become the following :

```
declare @answerXML xml = '<answers><answer part="1">answer,test0</answer><answer part="1">answer, test0</answer><answer part="1">answer,test1</answer><answer part="1">answer, test1</answer></answers>'
```

(Each node is duplicated, and in the added node, a **space** is added after the comma).

I was planing in using something like this :

```
SELECT 
    T.ref.value('.', 'varchar(256)') AS Answer 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [Xml] = @answerXML.query('for $i in data(/answers/answer) 
                                   return element temp { $i }')
    ) A
CROSS APPLY
    A.Xml.nodes('/temp') T(ref)
```

But no use, it seems it's too complicated.

Can anyone help in how to loop and update XML in T-SQL?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Is this the real structure? Why do you need this? What are you trying to solve with this duplication?

Comment: Yes this is the real structure. It's an xml that stores all possible values that the user can input. So if he inputs **answer,test0** or **answer, test0**, the input should be considered as a valid one.

Comment: I think, this design might be better with a mapping table. I'd maintain a table with all valid values and a `1:n` related table with all valid aliases. In this case you can join the user's input to your alias table and find the corresponding value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to shred the XML and rebuild it from scratch:

```
declare @answerXML xml=
'<answers>
  <answer part="1">answer,test0</answer>
  <answer part="1">answer,test1</answer>
</answers>';

SELECT a.value(N'@part',N'int') AS [answer/@part]
      ,a.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [answer] 
      ,''
      ,a.value(N'@part',N'int') AS [answer/@part]
      ,REPLACE(a.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)'),',',', ') AS [answer] 
FROM @answerXML.nodes(N'/answers/answer') AS A(a)
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('answers')
```

The result

```
<answers>
  <answer part="1">answer,test0</answer>
  <answer part="1">answer, test0</answer>
  <answer part="1">answer,test1</answer>
  <answer part="1">answer, test1</answer>
</answers>
```

Comment: Or shred the XML and insert into a table then query the table!

Comment: @JacobH What help / advantage would this bring? Using `.nodes()` there is a (volatile) derived table already...

Comment: Added the folowing condition to check if a comma exists. `WHERE CHARINDEX(',',a.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)'))>0`. Big Thanks -@Shnugo

Comment: The advantage of not having to shred and recreate the XML to store in a column each time you modify the data. But it sounds like you're happy with that process, so carry on!

Comment: @JacobH This sounds a little - uhm - supercilious... We both don't know, what the OP is doing here. If this is a one time action, if there is any need to keep this data for a second action... The main question is: Is XML the best place for this data at all? But this is the wrong place to discuss this...

Comment: @JacobH Did you read my comment below the question. Might be, it's this you are talking about...

Comment: @Shnugo Yep we're both on the same page. Seems to me like this could be done in a table and the XML is just an unnecessary step, but OP does seem satisfied with the result. Have an upvote and a good weekend :)

Comment: Originally i have an old table containing 2 columns, Id and XML value. I want to loop this table, and update each XML with the scenario mentioned in the original post. That's why this solution works for me, i can use the select to insert the modified values into a #temp table, than update the original one.